# how to automate a lot of repetitive actions in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How to automate a lot of repetitive actions in Visual Studio 2012?
Need to convert synchronic methods to async.
For example, need to do from

```
public void SomeMethod(String something)
{
     //action
}
public Some SomeMethodOneMore(String something)
{
    //action
}
```

to

```
public async Task SomeMethodAsync(String something)
{
     //action
}
public async Task<Some> SomeMethodOneMoreAsync(String something)
{
    //action
}
```

Comment: You convert them. The async keyword doesn't magically make the code asynchronous...

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+H and regular expressions

Comment: I think so too. Regex is the best way for this. But I don't like to work with regular expressions. It's not easy for me. And I was hoping that there is another way.

Comment: @DmitryBLR Regular expressions are the best way.  You just have to be careful to not change more then you want too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your type of work, you can get an awful lot done with careful use of SublimeText's multiple cursors.
See [this video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXuBgSpLpK4).

In Visual Studio I have 'Open with SublimeText' defined as an External Tool with a keyboard shortcut for Alt+O. Then whenever I need the multiple cursor functionality I can switch to it quickly.

The same functionality is also available as a [free extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2beb9705-b568-45d1-8550-751e181e3aef) for visual studio. See [Scott Hanselman's writeup](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimultaneousEditingForVisualStudioWithTheFreeMultiEditExtension.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the methods already have code in them, so in that vein, I don't think there is one single way.

In the past I have highlighted the common bit of code and simply done a manual find and replace.  It's slow and painful.

Comment: yes, you are right, it's slow and painful. I understand you very good. Estimation of this work is several weeks. I just try to do this more easy.

Comment: I feel your pain DmitryBLR, I've had to do this several times too and it hurts